# Interesting selection mysql

Tags: mysql

I have three tables - users, cities and regions.

```
users - u_id, u_city
cities - c_id, r_c_id
regions - r_id, r_alias
```

Where `users` and `cities` tie up by `u_city = c_id` and `cities` and `regions` by `r_c_id = r_id`. I have r_alias of regions table. Is it possible to take  count of users in that region i choose(i have r_alias) (`COUNT(u_id)`).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Just to correct your terminology - when you say 'tie up' you mean 'have a foreign key relationship' (u_city being the foreign key to city's c_id primary key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select count(u_id)
from users
join cities on u_city = c_id
join regions on r_c_id = r_id
where r_alias = "r_alias_value'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible.

You need to join the tables first,

```
SELECT  a.r_alias, COUNT(*) AS TotalUser
FROM    regions a
        INNER JOIN cities b
            ON a.r_id = b.r_c_id
GROUP   BY a.r_alias
```

This will list all regions with their specific number of users. If you want to count for a specified region, just add `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT  a.r_alias, COUNT(*) AS TotalUser
FROM    regions a
        INNER JOIN cities b
            ON a.r_id = b.r_c_id
WHERE   a.r_alias = 'valHERE'
GROUP   BY a.r_alias
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be rather more efficient to perform a select statement near

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
  r.*,
  COUNT(u.u_id) AS `users`

FROM (
  SELECT * FROM regions
  WHERE r_alias LIKE '$region_alias'
) AS r

LEFT OUTER JOIN cities AS c ON (r.r_id = c.r_c_id)

LEFT OUTER JOIN users  AS u ON (u.u_city = c.c_id)

GROUP BY r.r_id;
```

since it filters to a specific region before joining the remaining tables.

*(code was tested on MySQL 5.6.10)*